# Let $f$ be a continuous function on an interval around $0$ and let $a_i=f(\frac{1}{i})$ (for large enough $i$)

Tags: sequences-and-series, derivatives, continuity

Let $f$ be a continuous function on an interval around $0$ and let $a_i=f(\frac{1}{i})$ (for large enough $i$)

i) Suppose $\sum a_i$ converges. Must $f'(0)$ exist?

ii) Suppose $f(0) = f'(0) = 0$. Must $\sum a_i$ converge?

This is question #6 from Spivak Calculus 4th edition. I already showed that, if $\sum a_i$ converges, $f(0) = 0$, and also that, if $f'(0)$ exists and $\sum a_i$ converges, then $f'(0) = 0$, and also that if $f''(0)$ exists and $f'(0) = f(0) = 0$ then $\sum a_i$ converges.

Answer (score 1):

Hint for (i): What if $a_n=1/n$ for a sparse subsequence and $0$ otherwise? Easier: If I tell you the answer is "no," can you concoct a function $f$ that'll work?

Hint for (ii): Think about some of the "borderline" series that are close to converging but diverge. (Note by what you've shown that you want to contemplate $f'(0)=0$ but $f''(0)\ne 0$ or non-existent.) The number of derivatives of $f$ that vanish at $0$ dictate how quickly $a_n\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Ted, doesn't your first hint contradict continuity, or have I misunderstood 'sparse subsequence'?

Comment: @Daniel: I can certainly make a continuous function that is compatible with this, but perhaps that wasn't the easiest thing to suggest to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you already did 2 all that is left is to do 1. I can construct a function $f(x)$ such that it is not differentiable(let it be piecewise with the same value at 0, but vastly different slope like say -10000) therefore it might not be differentiable.